# passing event trigger as function arguement with jquery .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, arguments

i have a line of code to trigger a function when any of certain `<td>`s are clicked:

```
$("#grid .square").on( "click", move(e) );
```

it triggers the function, but it says `e` is undefined. how can i get it to pass on the element which triggers the event as a argument?

is there a way to do this with the other use if `.on()`?

something like:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#grid .square", move(e) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an anonymous function and pass the eventData parameter to the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function.
*You sure you don't know about anonymous?*

> **eventData**
>   Type: Object
>   An object containing data that will be passed to the event handler.

```
$("#grid").on('click',{anon:'PEOPLE POWER\nKNOWLEDGE IS POWER'}, function(event){
    move(event.data);
});
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5E92w/)

Comment: i do know about anonymous functions, and i thought of that actually, but it seemed kinda backwards. and anyway it doesnt work.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight I've updated my answer, I hope this gives more clarity :)

Comment: i need something more like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/5E92w/1/). (which isnt working)

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Just write `this` insteadof `event` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/5E92w/2/).

Comment: thanks for your help, right before i saw your comment i got it working with `$("#grid .square").on("click",function(event){move(event.target);});`